# How can I configure an SCP/SFTP file storage?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, scp, laravel-5.5

My Laravel application should copy files to another remote host. The remote host is accessible only via SCP with a private key. I would like to configure a new [file storage](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/filesystem) ([similarly as FTP](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/filesystem#driver-prerequisites)), but I have found no information, how to define an SCP driver.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

You'll need to install the [SFTP driver](https://flysystem.thephpleague.com/adapter/sftp/) for Flysystem, the library Laravel uses for its filesystem services:

```
composer require league/flysystem-sftp
```

Here's an example configuration that you can tweak. Add to the `disks` array in *config/filesystems.php*:

```
'sftp' => [
    'driver' => 'sftp',
    'host' => 'example.com',
    'port' => 21,
    'username' => 'username',
    'password' => 'password',
    'privateKey' => 'path/to/or/contents/of/privatekey',
    'root' => '/path/to/root',
    'timeout' => 10,
]
```

Extend Laravel's filesystem with the new driver by adding the following code to the `boot()` method of `AppServiceProvider` (or other appropriate service provider):

```
use Storage;
use League\Flysystem\Filesystem;
use League\Flysystem\Sftp\SftpAdapter;
...
public function boot()
{
    Storage::extend('sftp', function ($app, $config) {
        return new Filesystem(new SftpAdapter($config));
    });
}
```

Then you can use Laravel's API as you would for the local filesystem:

```
Storage::disk('sftp')->put('path/filename.txt', $fileContents);
```

Comment: Thank you. It looks promising. I installed the SFTP driver and added the configuration, but I receive the following error message: '[InvalidArgumentException] Driver [sftp] is not supported.'

Comment: I tried the configuration as described at: https://github.com/thephpleague/flysystem-sftp It works perfectly. I can not use the Storage facade, but it is ok for me.

Comment: It takes about 8-10 seconds to SFTP in, and list files. Am I doing something wrong ? or Is this normal for SFTP into a server and access files ?

Comment: @cyber8200 It depends on the number of files in the directory listing and the network conditions. Of course, a directory with thousands of files on a server in a different region will take much longer than one located in the same building with just a handful of files. If you're having trouble with latency from SFTP, and you need to list the contents of directories often, you might try fetching the list [via SSH](https://laravelcollective.com/docs/6.0/remote) instead. You may also want to check whether it's doing a recursive directory listing.

Comment: If I run the SCP command, it downloaded instantly, so the network connection is very fast.

Comment: how to delete file?

Answer (score 2):

Now, official documentation has instructions for SFTP connection:
https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/filesystem#sftp-driver-configuration

SFTP: `composer require league/flysystem-sftp "~1.0"`

> SFTP Driver Configuration Laravel's Flysystem integrations work great
> with SFTP; however, a sample configuration is not included with the
> framework's default filesystems.php configuration file. If you need to
> configure an SFTP filesystem, you may use the configuration example
> below:

```
'sftp' => [
        'driver' => 'sftp',
        'host' => 'example.com',
        'username' => 'your-username',
        'password' => 'your-password',
    
        // Settings for SSH key based authentication...
        'privateKey' => '/path/to/privateKey',
        'password' => 'encryption-password',
    
        // Optional SFTP Settings...
        // 'port' => 22,
        // 'root' => '',
        // 'timeout' => 30,
    ],
```