# How to store templates for non-php files in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, shell

We can store `PHP` template files using `blade` templating engine in Laravel. But, I want to create a config file on a remote server having more than 20-30 lines each.

Till now, I was doing this using `Perl`. I used to execute Perl file that used to dump contents in one file and I used to pass variables as parameters.

Now, I want to do it without using `Perl`. I tried looking for a solution but failed. To make it easy to understand, Here is what I am trying to do exactly!

I want to create the following config file on a remote server (Just an example).

**Example.conf**

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName example.com
    ServerAlias www.example.com
</VirtualHost>
```

Here, `example.com` and `www.example.com` will vary in every config file.

Now, I want to create this file from my laravel application to the remote server. **Is there any way I can store template of this config file and can compile and put file on remote server?**

I know how can I put this file on Remote server. I just want to know the best possible way to store template and customize  it when needed.

Comment: Just curious, do you want to manage configuration and automate deployment? because there are better tools for that, for example:  Ansible, Terraform, Chef, Puppet...

Comment: Your question is not pretty clear, could you maybe add an example or a context to this. From what I understand of your question, @Razor is right, you should use appropriate tools to do this, what you're doing is looking like a bad design and it could lead to a major security issue

Comment: @MauthieuAuclair example is already there. Read the question again please ...

Comment: Think carefully about sanitizing/validating input for this feature. If a malicious user manages to gain access to an endpoint that writes the template, they can potentially rewrite the configuration to allow all kinds of nasty things. That said, it's a neat idea. We can also use Laravel's [`sftp` filesystem driver](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46432109/5209322) to automatically upload the output file to a remote server.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can put it into `blade` template like `server-config.blade.php` and then when you want to place it on a a server you just call:

```
\File::put('place-on-the-server.conf', view('server-config')->render());
```

which will generate content based on the blade template (so you can pass variables to this template).

Comment: Is using a template engine really a good idea to use as a way to create server config files?

Comment: Why not? As you mentioned it's a "template" engine. It's design to create templates - not only frontend templates.

Comment: It feels like it's not right, however my "feelings" are not the law (thank god) so that's why I'm asking if it really is a good idea :)

Comment: What would not be a good idea is to give to `php-fpm` filesystem permissions to write the config file, but you may run it with `php-cli`, as the permission belongs to the user which run it (root for instance).

Comment: I have found using Laravel's blade engine for generating configurations/files really helpful to manage my files. I decided to wrap the engine as a cli for anyone who finds it useful https://github.com/surgiie/blade-cli

Answer (score 2):

As of my understanding, is that in your senario is that you have a website where people can request websites and you want to auto-generate the virtual-host file inside your application and then transfer this to the remote server?

May the above be the case then you have a lot of options.

### 1 - The answer of Filip

### 2 - Console commands

You can generate your file anyway you like. I personally have a structure in my laravel applications where I save blank files (templates). I then copy it over, and replace it with given parameters over console command, [Artisan Commands](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/artisan)

### 3 - Server scripts

Another way could be using Laravel Envoy. You will have a script on the server that will generate the file needed, and just call a function in your Envoy file of laravel to have it execute it. The good part about this is that you can make a new user on the server specifically for envoy and only allow it to run specific commands. This way theres very little way of messing up a server.[Envoy](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/envoy)